# Why does function cause this compiler warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'char[20]' from a function...

Tags: c

What is the problem in that function?

```
char printThis()
{
    char str[20] = "This is a string";
    return str;
}
```

I get a warning : Incompatible pointer to integer conversion  returning 'char[20]' from a function with result type char

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three problems that I can see:

1. You are returning `char*` but the function is declared to return `char`. The latter is just a single character rather than a string.
2. You are attempting to return memory that is only valid on the stack frame of the function. This is an error.
3. Your function is declared so that it can receive any number of arguments. Better to explicitly declare it to receive none with `void`.

Fix like this:

```
char* printThis(void)
{
    char* str = strdup("This is a string");
    return str;
}
```

Here I am using `strdup` to allocate the string on the heap. If you really wanted a buffer that was 20 characters long then you would need to use `malloc()` followed by `strcpy()`. Either way the responsibility for freeing the returned string is passed onto the caller.

Comment: Plus the caller must free() the string later.

Answer (score 2):

you declared your function returning a `char`, but you want to return a `char[]` which explains your warning.

Change your function declaration to return `char*`

Also, you will return a pointer locally allocated variable ( `str` ), so the pointer will point to a non-existent variable.

You have to manually alloc your string using `malloc`, or better using `strdup`, and then return it.

Don't forget to `free` the allocated pointer!

Strdup : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strdup.html

Answer (score 2):

Think return type should be `char*` and not `char`
Like this:

```
char* printThis()
{
    static char str[20] = "This is a string";
    return (char*)str;
}
```

Comment: That returns stack allocated memory.

Comment: @David, true, fixed it. But your solution seems better, though you have to remember freeing the string

Answer (score 0):

Because `char` is actually an integer type and `char []` actually a pointer (char *).
Change your declaration to `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

- The function is of type char, you are trying to return a value of type char*
- str is a locally allocated char-array. You cannot return it because it ceases to exists when the function ends.